# Does AWS IoT Core support binary messages in MQTT, such as CBOR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-iot

I am trying to deploy a Lambda function that processes messages from AWS IoT Core via MQTT using the Serverless Framework. The function works with JSON payloads, but I am having issues getting it to work with CBOR. When I use CBOR payload format, the Lambda function does not get triggered, and the message seems to disappear. Here is my configuration:

```yaml
functions:
  receiver:
    handler: app/receiver/handle.handler
    events:
      - iot:
          sql: "SELECT decode(encode(*, 'base64'), 'base64') AS value FROM 'sdk/test/python'"
```

JSON messages arrive as expected, but CBOR messages do not. The handler function simply prints anything it receives to stdout. My question is whether IoT Core supports only JSON payload format, or if I am doing something incorrectly.

Python publisher

```
publish_future = mqtt_connection.publish(topic='sdk/test/python', payload=cbor2.dumps(payload), qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE)

publish_future[0].result()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it supports binary formats.

Solved by changing code to this:

```
functions:
  receiver:
    handler: app/receiver/handle.handler
    events:
      - iot:
          sql: "SELECT decode(encode(*, 'base64'), 'base64') AS value FROM 'sdk/test/python'"
          sqlVersion: '2016-03-23'
```